# Facebook App Error on Facebook Registration Form Code

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have created an app on facebook for Facebook Registeration Form using

```
<iframe style="border: none; width: 96%; margin-left: 2%;" src="https://www.facebook.com/plugins/registration?client_id=ID;redirect_uri=URL &amp;fields=name,birthday,gender,location,email" frameborder="no" scrolling="auto" width="100%" height="330"></iframe>
```

but it is returning below error.

> Unable to load the registration form for Software Signup. You may have previously blocked this app on Facebook. Go to your Facebook privacy settings to unblock this app. (Error: That 'redirect_uri' isn't allowed for that client_id.)

I checked my privacy setting and find that I haven't blocked it. How can I resolve

> Error: That 'redirect_uri' isn't allowed for that client_id.

Comment: I've voted to close as 'unable to reproduce' since this question appears to be abandoned.

Answer (score 1):

The following is wrong:

```
...client_id=ID;redirect_uri=URL &amp;fields=...
```

It needs to be

```
...client_id=YOUR_APP_ID&redirect_uri=YOUR_REDIRECT_URI&fields=...
```

as described here:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/registration/#usage

The YOUR_REDIRECT_URI must be the same as you set for your app under https://developers.facebook.com/apps/ -> Settings of your app